# I wanted to ask about java program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am a java programmer and i want to ask that why is my program not working:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JTextArea; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 

public class Cool extends JFrame{ 

    public void AL(){ 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setSize(500 , 200); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setTitle("Java"); 

        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(); 
        textarea.setEditable(false); 
        textarea.setLineWrap(true); 

        JTextField field = new JTextField(); 
        field.setText("Hi! This is the text!"); 

    } 
}
```

this is my main class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Cool dude = new Cool();
        dude.AL();
    }
}
```

It does not display anything just a blank JFrame.It does give the title but nothing else it has everything.

Comment: You have never added your components to the main frame!

Comment: You might find it helpful to read through the [Swing Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the JTextArea and the JTextField to the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you adding the widgets to the `JFrame`, so why should they appear?

```
frame.add(textarea);
frame.add(field);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) nor the [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) to the [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). You can do it through the method `add` which is inherited from [`Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29). According to Java Docs:

> Appends the specified component to the end of this container.

**Code:**

```
frame.add(textarea);
frame.add(field);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there are a good half-dozen answers with the same answer: you should add the elements to your frame. But I also wanted to add that you usually want to encapsulate your `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane` so that you can write more text that will be shown using scroll bars.

You should also make sure that you're adding your elements to a content pane with a layout manager so that the elements will get arranged in the way that you expect. Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to familiarize yourself with the available layout managers. An additional, popular layout manager is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) although it requires an external Jar file.

Below is a simple example with my suggestions:

[image: An application with a text field and area]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Cool extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Cool frame = new Cool();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Cool() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        textField = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(30);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTextArea txtrImAText = new JTextArea();
        txtrImAText.setRows(10);
        txtrImAText.setColumns(30);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtrImAText);

        pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the elements to the frame:

```
frame.add(textarea );
frame.add(field);
```

Add thise lines and you will see a result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add text area and text field to the `JFrame` in AL method

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setSize(500 , 200); 
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setTitle("Java"); 

    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(); 
    textarea.setEditable(false); 
    textarea.setLineWrap(true); 

    JTextField field = new JTextField(); 
    field.setText("Hi! This is the text!"); 

    frame.add(textarea);  // <-- here
    frame.add(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used swing, but it seems that you have to add textarea and field to your JFrame frame.

Looking on the net i have seen this example:
frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);